# How to run many HTTP connections in android?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I have a list with id's which i'm going to use in URL's, to get some data using HttpConnection. I was trying to use AsyncTask from the loop, but it was a bad idea, because my program crashed with:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 124606360 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 103MB until OOM
```

How to make many connections one after another correctly?

Comment: This has nothing to do with "many connections". You are attempting to allocate a ~120MB block of heap space, and that will fail nearly all of the time.

Comment: how many records you are getting in request?

Comment: `to get some data` What kind of data? And where do you want to put it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try method new AsyncTask().executeOnExecutor()

or Use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add `android:largeHeap="true"` your in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Or you can try using network library such us Volley, Okhttp, Retrofit, etc.